# String and Null Exception check through Try and Catch Block

Tags: java, logging, exception, log4j, double

The following code to try to catch a empity double inputvia logging is not working. I also want to check if a user added a string in the input field by mistake (but I am having trouble writing the query). Can someone please look at this and guide me.

```
try {
    if (results1 != 00.00) {
        throw new Exception("Data must be added");
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {  
    log.error("You have an error", e);
}
```

The user must enter a value for results1 as it is used for a calculation. Results1 is a double as it is a percentage, I am willing to change it to an int if thats what it takes to make it work. I also want to check through the try and catch technique if a user accidently added a % sign. I want my logger to catche the NumberFormatException for testing purposes.

I think this might be the problem:

```
      (results1 != 00.00)
```

Is this the best way to check if the input is empty for a double. Also How can i check if a string is added?

Comment: what type is results1?

Comment: result1 is a double. But if needed I can change it to a int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has the function Double.parseDouble(string), which will throw a NumberFormatException if it is unable to convert the string to a double.

//EDIT

Combined with prashant answer, here is a full implementation.

```
try {
    Double result = Double.parseDouble(string);

    //This is required to check that number is a valid Percentage value
    if(!(result > 0 && result < 100)){
       //You will have to create this custom exception or throw a simple exception
       throw new InvalidPercentageCustomException(result + " is not a valid Percentage");
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
//Do Something
}
```

Comment: There is no need to catch (Exception e), the top level exception. we can just catch NullPointerException & NumberFormatException as parseDouble only throws either of them. This improves readability & enables us to implement better exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea that using '==' or '!=' for double, float. You can compare with pretty small number instead of equal sign ('==').

```
 Math.abs(result1)  > 0.001
```

Comment: Why > 0.001, and not >= 0.01? That´s the point. It depends on the precision that result1 has. Anyways +1

Comment: 0.01 or 0.001 is does not matter. Double and float precision has more accuracy both of them.

Comment: No. If result contains 0.002 (instead of 0) due to precision loss in previous steps, and we are talking about currency, then it makes a huge difference if you consider it to be equal to zero or not.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to check if the user input (which is string) is a valid percentage or not.

You can make use of parseDouble like this:

```
try{
     Double result = Double.parseDouble(results);

     //This is required to check that number is a valid Percentage value
     if(result <= 0.0 || result >= 100.0){
         //You will have to create this custom exception or throw a simple exception
         throw new InvalidPercentageCustomException("Not a valid Percentage");
     }
}
catch(Exception e){
//Do Something
}
```

Also one advice: You should not be willing change your data type just to make your program work.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you have to check the NumberFormatException. Below program has three examples.  First is a success scenario, second is a empty String with parse exception and the third is a String with parse exception

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;

public class ParseCheck {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String results1 = "123.56";
        String results2 = "";
        String results3 = "xyz";

        try {
            Double.parseDouble(results1);
            System.out.println(results1 + "  parsed successfully");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(results2);
            System.out.println(results2 + "parsed successfully");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(results3);
            System.out.println(results3 + "parsed successfully");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```